# Use my own Rectangle struct instead of the built-in Rectangle

Tags: c#, overriding

I recently created a Rectangle `struct`. Another `struct` with the same name exists in XNA.

How can I tell the program to use my `struct` over the built-in one without a name collision?

I also want to still be able to use the built-in one (for a construct to take a normal `Rectangle` and translate it into mine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just fully qualify the type. For example, if your root namespace is `MyProject`, use `MyProject.Rectangle`. I don't know what `Rectangle` is in XNA, but one full qualification of a `Rectangle` structure is `System.Drawing.Rectangle`.

Comment: if you have a long fully qualified name, use the using directive to shorten it: `using MyRectangle = MyProject.Foo.Bar.Baz.Rectangle;` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/sf0df423(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Fantastic, I was unaware you could define a type. I'll work this into the project somehow. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add [implicit conversion operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx) between your struct and the other.